# Flask - Printing a value from a dict

Tags: python, database, list, dictionary, flask

View:

```
cur = g.db.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "Bozo1"')
printme = [dict(id=row[0], username=row[1], password=row[2]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
```

Template:

```
{% print(printme) %}
```

Prints:

```
[{'id': 1, 'username': 'Bozo1', 'password': 'abc123'}]
```

Normally in Python, I would just do print(printme["id"]) which would output 1.  But in Flask, this method is not working for me.

Comment: Is that your full code ? You mixing python code and a template tag. This can't work. You must set printme in the python code then send it to a template where you can use {{printme}} to "print" it

Comment: No its not the full code but I figured it's relavent enough.  I'll update the OP.

Comment: @gawel I updated the OP.  Thats neat that you can do {{printme}} without needing to type the print function.  Unfortunately, it didn't help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Normally in Python, I would just do print(printme["id"]) which would output 1.

No, what you would get is `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str` as `printme` is a `list` of `dicts`, not a `dict` itself. Assuming you want to print out all of the returned results, you need to loop over `printme`:

```
{% for result in printme() %}
    {{ result['id'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you only want to print the first one, you could do:

```
{{ printme[0]['id'] }}
```

But it would make more sense to only fetch one result instead.

Comment: Yeah I did that yesterday.  I work with a lot of multidimensional arrays at work so that was one of the first things I went for.  I recognized the [] around the dict.  But still I errored out... Today, however, it started up the server and tried again the way you showed and it worked.  I don't know what I was doing yesterday but I can't recreate the errors.  I could swear I did it exactly as you did before I asked the question but who knows at this point.  Thanks for the help!